# Java Regular Expression check

Tags: java, regex

I have the code as

```
  String s = "The loading is completed, TB62 is bound for Chongqing, and trains 11-13 are expected";

    boolean matcher = Pattern.matches(".*11-13.*", s);
    System.out.println(matcher);
```

I am only checking for string containing 11-13 and above workds but if the regular expression is

```
.*1-13.*
```

that also works for the above string. How do I change regular expression that it will won't match `.*1-13.*` but only `.*11-13.*` should match

**Updating and adding more info so people can answer**

I have two regular expressions

```
.*11-13.*
.*1-1.*
```

But the issue is even

```
.*1-1.*  also matches to the string 




String s = "The loading is completed, TB62 is bound for Chongqing, and trains 11-13 are expected";
```

It should not match because I want to regular expression `.*11-13.*` to match only. I think I need to modify regular expression

Comment: Can you state the problem clearly

Comment: Err.. You said it yourself. "only `.*11-13.*` should match".... Is there a reason that pattern won't work?

Comment: *"How do I change regular expression that it will won't match `.*1-13.*` but only `.*11-13.*` should match"* ... that sentence makes no sense to me.

Comment: @Tom I have updated the questions now.

Comment: This is still unclear. You know you have two two-digit numbers separated by a minus/dash, so why do you have the `.*1-1.*` regex in the first place? What other numbers can exist? Is 100-123 possible and is that valid? How about 99-99?

Comment: in other words, you want to match a *word* like `1-1`?

Comment: @Tom Because there are some strings where we also have 1-1 so that regular expression match to that.

Comment: @user15244370 Yes

Comment: try `".*\\b1-13\\b.*"`  `\\b` matches a word boundary  [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#word_boundary)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For that use *word boundary* **\b**:

```
Pattern.matches(".*\\b11-13\\b.*", s);
```

Take a look at the javadoc of `Pattern`.

For instance if you could have line breaks in the text, either use `DOT_ALL` (dot is also newline) with compile, or simply use `find` instead of `match`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `Pattern#matches`, which matches the whole string, you can use `Matcher#find` as shown below:

```
import java.util.regex.MatchResult;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "The loading is completed, TB62 is bound for Chongqing, and trains 11-13 are expected";
        Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\b11-13\\b").matcher(s);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group());
        }

        // Alternatively
        Pattern.compile("11-13").matcher(s).results().map(MatchResult::group).forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
11-13
11-13
```

**Note:** `\b` is a [boundary matcher](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/bounds.html). If you need a regex for any pair of hyphen-separeted integers consisting of two digits, you can use `\b\d{2}-\d{2}\b` as the regex.

Comment: Is this Java 9 or something? I am still using Java 8

Comment: @Makky - The alternative solution [requires Java9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#results--) but the first solution will work even with Java7.

Comment: But the problem still persists. Even "1-13" matching to the string which should not Only 11-13 sould match
If I have regular expression "1-13" it should not match

Comment: @Makky - You can use `\\d{2}-\\d{2}` which mandates two digits before and after the hyphen.